# Is Jglue (CDI-unit) still available?

Tags: java, unit-testing, cdi, cdi-unit

On some projects i'm using jglue in order to test with CDI injection support.

The server "jglue.org" and maven repository are no longer reachable. Does anyone know what happens?

Comment: Nope no idea. Arquillian is pretty nice testing solution for cdi

Comment: Arquillian is pretty but requires server deployment. It slows unit tests. I just want inject my mock. If jglue is no longer available, i need to manually inject these mocks.

Answer (score 3):

I had some hosting issues in December. Since then we've moved the artefacts to Maven central. Sorry about the downtime.